# If I choose Refresh on windows 8, does it format my hard drives besides C:?

Tags: windows, windows-8-refresh

I have my important stuffs and apps on another drive. I was wondering that if I make a refresh, does it also format or delete F: G: drives as well? How about the desktop files, will they be lost?

Comment: This doesn't in the slightest bit relate to programming. Expect this question to be closed shortly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do Windows 8 Refresh and Reset my PC really do?](http://superuser.com/questions/492792/what-do-windows-8-refresh-and-reset-my-pc-really-do), [What, *specifically* does Windows 8's “Refresh Your PC” option delete and retain?](http://superuser.com/questions/514247/what-specifically-does-windows-8s-refresh-your-pc-option-delete-and-retain) etc.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will not lose your files and all Metro/Modern UI applications will be reinstalled automatically, but you will need to reinstall all classic windows apps. [More info here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc).