# Is the reset your machine feature the same as a complete re-install of Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

Lately windows has been getting unbearably slow, so I decided to reset my machine (i tried to do a refresh but it kept failing)

After I've done the reset, I feel the computer is still slow. The weird thing is it's kind of a different type of slow. Everything inside chrome runs really well, but inside Windows itself, when changing windows, clicking on icons etc. it keeps locking up.

I used Windows 8's reset my computer feature. Is that feature the same as just doing a fresh install of the OS on my hard drive? If so how would it do this since it never asked for an ISO file or a DVD?

Also, does that mean that given my computer is still sluggish, it means it's not a software problem (maybe a hardware problem?) given it still hasn't gone awaY?

Answer (score 0):

Answering your title question, please refer to [this](https://superuser.com/q/492792/179299) post. 
I take no credit whatsoever for it.

Addressing the sluggishness, is your hard drive being defragmented by a scheduled task? if it isn't, please defrag it.

Check your hard drive on BIOS, if you are not on AHCI mode but rather on ATA, check if 32 bit transfer is enabled.

Use [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-PT/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to diagnose possible unwanted startup entries causing the sluggishness.

Give `sfc /scannow` a chance. if windows gets currupted to a point the repair functions are affected, this is your only chance - except a format from the DVD directly that is.