# Does a Windows 8 system reset remove malware?

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, malware, reset, malware-removal

I think I may have gotten a virus/malware. According to the first answer to this post:

[How do I get rid of malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

I should do a re-format of the disk. But because I have an upgrade license a clean install would be hard, so I would like to use the reset option on the installation disk. In a comment on the answer mentioned above Joel Coehoorn states about the reset option:

*@ConradFrix Too soon to say... I haven't needed to do this to a Windows 8 PC yet... but I'm pessimistic because it doesn't result in reformatting the drive. Windows 8 includes several security improvements, including running antivirus software from time 0 as part of the OS, such that I'm hopeful to never need to do this for Windows 8 at all. –  Joel Coehoorn Nov 30 '12 at 20:11*

I went on to search what the reset option was about and found this post:

[What do Windows 8 Refresh and Reset my PC really do?](https://superuser.com/questions/492792/what-do-windows-8-refresh-and-reset-my-pc-really-do)

According to the first answer: "*The Windows RE erases and formats the hard drive partitions on which Windows and personal data reside.*" when you choose the menu option: "*Remove everything and reinstall*"

I guess the reset option corresponds to this option in the settings menu. So my question is: **Does the reset option lead to the removal of all malware and viruses on a computer with different partitions?**

Additional details: I have three other partitions on the disk containing a Linux installation and a defect recovery partition, after resetting Windows I plan to reinstall Linux as well. I don't know what I should do with the recovery partition.

Node: I am planning to perform the reset by using a Windows installation disk.

Edit: Tried out the reset option and it isn't working so the question is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the malware has not gotten into your recovery partition, yes, it will destroy it. However, if the malware has gotten into the recovery partition, no, it will not. I suggest installing one of the more powerful Linux antivirus apps like [Bitdefender](http://www.bitdefender.com/) ([free for personal use](http://download.bitdefender.com/repos/)) ([application notes](http://unices.bitdefender.com/)) and then scan all partitions on the drive.

Comment: I am not planning to use the recovery partition (it's a windows vista recovery partition), since I have the installation disk used in the upgrade. Would it still be a problem then?

Answer (score 0):

Beware! "Windows Reset" = "Clean installation" without the actual trouble! This means that Windows will get rid of all your software (I'm not sure about files) like it were at first day before installing anything! You surely don't want that! If I was going to do all the trouble reinstalling everything, I would rather do it the traditional way, that is backup all my data and then format the disk, to make sure no trace of virus is left in it. Be careful with "Windows Refresh" and "Windows Reset" options! Read two-three times what they do and make sure you understand it before doing it!

Just read it, Refresh keeps all your data and installed Windows Apps (Metro Apps), but NOT installed programs (desktop apps in new Windows 8 jargon). So you have to reinstall everything but you don't lose your files (well, I wouldn't bet on it). On the other hand, Reset deletes EVERYTHING and returns Windows to the "first run after installation" state, without any data or software installed! Be careful! So a Reset only if you have no choice. If you have the older version of Windows and the upgrade DVD, I would recommend a clean install to make sure no trace of virus is left in your disk. Believe me, it's worth it the extra effort. It will save you a second format in case some virus do stay in your hard disk hidden somewhere...

Comment: I know I will lose all my programs and my files are back-uped, but I think I can easily reinstall then (I do that every half year for linux). About the format option, I don't have a licence for a clean windows install. So I should go to the shop where I bought the computer and ask if they have recovery disks. But I am wondering if the differences between a reset and a full reinstall are significant when removing viruses?