# Recovering the data lost due to windows refresh

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-8-refresh

I performed the windows 8 "refresh" and all the applications (downloaded) are gone along with its data.  Is there any way I could get that data back ?

Comment: A Refresh operation does not delete personal files.  So your personal files are still there you just have to locate them.  You will have to reinstall your desktop applications, you were warned this would be the case, before you performed the oepration.  Any Windows Store applications you had installed, will automatically, be installed again.

Comment: The application data may be in C:\Windows.old see http://www.hanselman.com/blog/RefreshYourPCInWindowsAppDataAndMyMissingMinecraftWorlds.aspx

Answer (score 1):

> I performed the windows 8 "refresh" and all the applications
>   (downloaded) are gone along with its data.

By using the Refresh operation you were told this was exactly what would happen.  You were presented the following warning before you confirmed the operation.

> Apps you installed from websites and DVDs will be removed. Apps that
>   came with your PC and apps you installed from the Windows Store will
>   be reinstalled. Windows puts a list of removed apps on your desktop
>   after refreshing your PC.

So you should be looking on the desktop for this folder.

> Is there any way I could get that data back ?

If you actually performed a Refresh then a list of your installed programs was generated and placed on your desktop.  Additionally any data that could not be migrated is now located in `C:\Windows.old\`.

Any files that were located in `C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\` are now located in `C:\Windows.old\users\YOURNAME\AppData\` **unless** you ran the cleanup tool and deleted the data.  If that happen then data recovery is unlikely.

[image]

[Related Question](https://superuser.com/questions/492792/what-do-windows-8-refresh-and-reset-my-pc-really-do)

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc)

[Additional Reading](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/RefreshYourPCInWindowsAppDataAndMyMissingMinecraftWorlds.aspx)