# For the purpose of Windows 10 reset, what are considered apps?

Tags: windows-10, system-restore, reset

Windows 10 has an option to do a PC reset that keeps your personal files, but uninstalls any apps and drivers you have installed.

What are considered personal files and what are considered apps for this? For example, I got 600 GB of games installed, are these considered apps or personal files? Is my dropbox desktop client considered an app or a personal file? Are apps just the ones you install through the Windows 10 store, or also any other apps you may have installed?

Comment: Any application you download from. Windows Store, is considered an "app"  Your personal files are documents contained within the profile directory.  Any desktop (Win32) application installed would have to be installed again. "got 600 GB of games installed, are these considered apps or personal files?" - You will have to install these again since they are Win32 applications I presume.

Comment: @Ramhound I see. Any reason why you posted that as a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: I specifically recall a question that asked this a year ago, and I specifcally recall submitting ( or reading) an answer to it, I just can't find it.

Comment: [Relevant](http://superuser.com/questions/492792/what-do-windows-8-refresh-and-reset-my-pc-really-do).  Windows 8.1 Refresh/Reset work identically, only difference is, Windows 10 doesn't use different images to reinstall Windows its simply called "Reset" and allows you keep or not keep your personal files.

Comment: [Related](http://superuser.com/questions/941146/windows-10-will-the-reset-feature-save-appdata)