# How can I preserve the WSL linux environment while doing a Windows 10 system "reset?"

Tags: windows-10, backup, windows-backup, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[This post](https://superuser.com/questions/1164818/how-to-backup-wsl-linux-subsystem-for-windows-10-before-system-reset-or-reins) mentions simply restoring the WSL directory partially restored WSL, but with some functionality issues. [This post](https://superuser.com/a/1199498/141182) gives generic information for how to back up and recover a linux installation. [This post](https://superuser.com/a/941458/141182) says that %appdata% is in fact moved into your Windows.old folder, which is created after reset and contains your "old" files.
)
What information might have gotten lost in the first posters experiment? Are there some registry settings or configuration files that would allow simply restoring the Linux root directory (`%USERPROFILE%/AppData/Local/lxss`) to work?

**EDIT**

My question was marked as a duplicate of [How to backup (WSL) Linux Subsystem for Windows 10, before system reset or reinstall?](https://superuser.com/questions/1164818/how-to-backup-wsl-linux-subsystem-for-windows-10-before-system-reset-or-reins).

However that question was only about how to back up the installation--basically tar it and save it somewhere. I explicitly ask about how to restore it.

Comment: As a side note, I recommend using some configuration management tool like `chef` to store your WSL configuration as a code. This way you can always nuke your current installation and provision it again on a fresh linux image.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Please see my edit as to why it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @fixer1234 Once again -- this is how to restore it, not how to back it up. This is not a duplicate question.

Comment: For those of you who are not familiar with WSL, this is a completely different issue than backing up and restoring a linux partition.

Comment: You may look at this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1344203/756164)

Comment: @fixer1234 -- can you please remove the flag. As now stated the question is explicitly about how to restore it. Also, the most recent comment links to another answer that is the first I have found that actually addresses that issue.

Comment: @Jaime -- thanks for the link. Nice that there are some explicit solutions coming down the pipe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to backup (WSL) Linux Subsystem for Windows 10, before system reset or reinstall?](https://superuser.com/questions/1164818/how-to-backup-wsl-linux-subsystem-for-windows-10-before-system-reset-or-reins)

Comment: @phuclv You clearly didn't read the post or the discussion above. Please remove the flag. Thank you.

Comment: well obviously I've read the comments before voting. The other question has the instructions to restore wsl

Comment: @phuclv if you look carefully, you will see that Jaime added his answer to that question three days ago, consequently rendering my question a "duplicate." Jaime had to choose which similar questions to answer as he could not post the same answer twice. That is why he linked to his answer to the other question in his above comment. If he had posted his answer here instead, it would have rendered the other question a "duplicate." It is no my fault he added an answer to the other question 3 days ago. Flagging my question as a duplicate makes me look bad, and is not fair. Please remove the flag.

Answer (score 3):

Very old question that got bumped today, and things have changed a lot in the 4 years since the question was asked.  I actually did a "Reset" on my daily-driver a few years ago and had a similar situation.

Back then, the best you could really do would be to copy any *data* out of the old filesystem.  When this question was asked, that filesystem was typically (as you mention in the question) somewhere under `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\lxss`.  I'll take your word for it, since I don't recall exactly, and I don't have any installations that old around any longer.

At some point, probably when WSL started supporting multiple distributions, the WSL1 folder changed to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\<PackageName>\LocalState\rootfs`.  When I did a reset on my PC several years ago, I did `tar` up that directory and then restored individual files (but not the entire filesystem, as you ask) after the Reset and WSL re-installation.  I didn't consider the `Windows.old`, but that would have been a valid way to get at those files as well.

Nowadays, yes, *before* doing a reset, a `wsl --export` can be performed as mentioned in the other answer here.

But if the user doesn't think to do this, it *may* still be possible to completely restore the filesystem after the Reset using `Windows.old`.  There are two scenarios:

- WSL2 makes this fairly easy, as the entire filesystem is stored in a virtual drive in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\<PackageName>\LocalState\rootfs\ext4.vhdx`.  See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1609866/1210833) for details, but you can basically just copy that `ext4.vhdx` out of `Windows.old` and into a new installation.
- With WSL1, I'm *90% confident* that you can recover a WSL installation from `Windows.old` using the following method.

  1. First, install a distribution from the Store.  I know, you want to recover your *old* install, but we're going to use this new install to do that.  You can always uninstall the Store distribution when we are done.
  2. Launch that distribution.
  3. Create `/etc/wsl.conf` with the following:

     ```
     [automount]
     options = "metadata"
     ```
  4. Next,

     ```
     cd /mnt/C/Windows.old/Users/<yourusername>/AppData/Local/Packages/<PackageName>/LocalState/rootfs
     ```

     `<PackageName>` will depend on your distribution, but will be start with `Canonical...` for Ubuntu distributions.  If your WSL install is old enough, it may be `/mnt/C/Windows.old/Users/<yourusername>/AppData/Local/lxss`.  When you do `ls` there, you want to see the `/` directory of that installation.
  5. From within that directory, `tar cvf recovery.tar .`.  It will take a while for a WSL1 installation.
  6. `sudo mv recovery.tar <somewhere>` else on the `C:` drive; something like `/mnt/c/Users/<youruser>/Documents/wsl` (it's close to what I use for this).  This will be the new location of the distribution when we're done.
  7. Exit WSL
  8. From PowerShell, navigate to the directory where you placed `recovery.tar`.
  9. `mkdir OldUbuntu` (or whatever you want to call it)
  10. `wsl --import OldUbuntu .\OldUbuntu .\recovery.tar`.  The command also optionally takes a `--version 1/2` (at the end) to force the WSL version.
  11. If desired, make this your default WSL installation with `wsl --set-default OldUbuntu`.
  12. Launch the distribution with `wsl ~ -d OldUbuntu`.  The `-d/--distribution` argument is only required if you didn't set it as default above.
  13. Create a `/etc/wsl.conf` with the following contents:

      ```
      [user]
      default=username
      ```

      Edit `username` to be whatever your username was in the distribution before you Reset Windows.
  14. Optionally uninstall the distribution that we installed and used for creating the tarball.

  That should be it.  I've actually tested this with a slightly different scenario.  I installed a WSL1 instance, then I went through the process above on it from another instance.  I was able to successfully `--import` it after going through the above steps.  File/directory ownership and permissions look to be correct, as do symlinks.  My only concern is whether a really old WSL distribution may use different metadata.

  **Warning**:  Please only try this on a WSL1 filesystem if you have no other way to recover it.  Accessing files in a WSL1 filesystem through `%AppData%` (or equivalent) is [known to cause corruption](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/).  That's why I created a throwaway instance myself in order to try this out.

  *Side note*:  You might think about `tar`'ing the files in `Windows.old` from within Windows, rather than going through the hassle of installing another WSL instance.  My concern here is that this will not capture the *Linux* ownership and permissions, which will likely result in a corrupted installation when `wsl --import`'ing.

Comment: This looked like it was going to work, but when I try to actually launch the imported distro, I get an error 0xd000020c.  Any thoughts?