# Clean install using the reset computer option

Tags: windows, reset

I found this extremely useful topic about how to [perform a clean install using Reset this PC in Windows 10](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-win_upgrade/how-to-perform-a-clean-install-using-reset-this-pc/6f6335fc-8d15-4598-af16-033d1d8c16bf)

1. I go to Start > Settings > Update & security > Reset  ->Get Started
2. I get these 2 options: "Keep my files" and "Remove everything".

(I click in the second one)

3. A new panel shows in and I get to choose between 2 options: "Reset all drives" and "Reset drive where windows is installed".

Which one should I choose? I mean, I want to just delete all my apps and files. I don't want to get rid of Windows 10. There used to be an option called "Just remove my files" but I can't find it anymore (I guess it has been replaced by the "reset all drives" and "reset drive where windows is installed").

Comment: Really, this is not a question.

Comment: I've edited your question to make the question more apparent. Hope you don't mind :-)

Comment: @Xavierjazz I fail to see how this is not a question. There is a question mark so it is a question. If you don't have anything useful to say then don't comment.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the (intended) definition of "drive", but it sounds like they meant "partition"?

(May be related to  [What do Windows 8 Refresh and Reset my PC really do?](https://superuser.com/questions/492792/what-do-windows-8-refresh-and-reset-my-pc-really-do) )

It sounds like the reset is a nuke-and-pave process, so full format and reinstall.

I'd stay away from the "reset all drives" option, in case that really does what it sounds like it does (wipe all DRIVES).

The "where windows is installed" option should do only that partition, assuming MS didn't seriously goof there.

Of course, if you only have one drive with only Windows' partition on it (no other storage partitions/drives), it's a moot point, since both will do the same thing.