# Location and security of installation files used in reset process by Windows 10

Tags: windows, security

Windows 10 has a built-in reset feature. When the system has problems user can use this feature to reset Windows, instead of the classic method that we use since DOS days, formatting the drive and installing OS from scratch.

I wonder how safe is resetting Windows using this feature comparing to old manual format/install method and whether a paranoid user is able to use this reset feature with peace of mind or should he/she still use old manual format/install method.

My questions to measure the safety of the built-in reset process:

1. Where does Windows keep installation files on the drive?
2. What measures does Windows take to keep installation files genuine and secure, to protect them against malware and file corruptions?

Comment: Check this thread out : http://superuser.com/questions/492792/what-do-windows-8-refresh-and-reset-my-pc-really-do

Comment: Thank you, it is indeed related and helpful, but I can't find answer to my questions about the location and safety of installation files.